# One row at a time with 20 second break

Tags: python-3.x, excel

I have thought about my question and I am stuck on this part.

I just want to use information in row one.  Then sleep for a minute.

Then use information in row 2, and so on.

```
 df = pd.read_csv("AA.csv", header=0)
 row_number = 1
 row = df.iloc[row_number,:]
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question you want to wait for a specific period of time after reading each row of excel

There is module in Python for this type of operation known as `time`

### Python time.sleep() Function

The `sleep()` function suspends (delays) execution of the current thread for the given number of seconds.

Basic Coding:

```
import time
time.sleep(20)
print("Printed after 20 seconds.")
```

In your case you have to use sleep() function after reading each row of excel

```
...

import time

# Read first row of excel
time.sleep(20)
# Read Second row of excel
time.sleep(20)

...
```

### UPDATE

After fully understanding your requirement you can use the below code:

```
# This code imports the openpyxl and time modules.
import openpyxl
import time

# This line opens the Excel workbook and gets the first worksheet.
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

# This line gets the maximum row number in the worksheet.
mr = ws1.max_row

# This loop iterates through all the rows in the worksheet, starting from row 2.
for i in range(2, mr+1):

    # This line gets the value of the cell in the current row and column 1.
    data = (ws1.cell(row=i, column=1).value)

    # This line pauses the execution of the code for 20 seconds.
    time.sleep(20)

# This line closes the Excel workbook.
wb1.close()
```

Comment: thanks for reply.  How would this go in an loop that ends when last row of excel file is reached?

Comment: Glad to help you,To achieve that you have to use `openpyxl` module of python.

Comment: I can't add that for python 3.  I have tried

Comment: I had used Pandas = df = pd.read_csv("AA.csv", header=0)
row_number = 1
row = df.iloc[row_number,:]   .....   I can use this row fine.  I just want to loop through rows with 30 second gap.  I want to use information from row one then get loop to sleep 30 seconds.  then use row 2 and so on

Comment: I just don't know how to put all in a loop

Comment: I really need help with this.  I cannot get to work.

Comment: As per your requirement I updated my answer, If my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) helps you accept my answer and also upvote.